# Event-sourcing and sagas - compensating transactions

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, distributed-transactions, event-sourcing

First question on SO (really???), so bear with me please :)

We're architecting a solution using event sourcing. Some of our business processes will be long-running, thus we're planning on using **sagas** to orchestrate commands to **several aggregate roots**.

In my understanding, if a saga-issued command should **fail**, the saga would be responsible to issue **compensating commands** to all the previously invoked aggregate roots.

What should be the course of action if the state of an aggregate root would be **mutated externally** (i.e. by some other process/user) **after** it takes part in the saga, but **before** the saga fails and **issues a compensating command** to that aggregate root?

In other words, how would one try to compensate for an **event that is not the last one** in a certain aggregate root's event stream (speaking in EventStore lingo)?

Comment: I guess you could either rely on information in the event or in the AR itself to see if the compensating action can still occur. If not, then you may kick off a process that requires a manual resolution of the conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather tricky situation since what I am seeing is that you may end up with an invalid AR *after* your compensating entry, making your compensating action invalid.

You are probably going to have to re-look at the design of the process such that changes to ARs are not made until you are sure that your process manager (saga) will be able to complete.  Perhaps temporarily storing the values for later change.

Another approach may be to prevent certain commands on your AR should it be in a certain state that indicates that it may lead to issues for those commands.  The user would then not be able to issue those commands.  Your process manager would take care of *that* state and any state expiries/timeouts and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've got some comments though. Your first proposed solution looks a lot like locking, which would probably lead to performance issues. The second proposal assumes the ARs would be gnostic of their participation in a saga, which is in my opinion against the saga principle whereby only the saga knows orchestration details and ARs are just being invoked.

Comment: I don't think storing values for later use is much like locking at all :) The second option *may* be required only to get the saga to work but if it is a bother then another solution may be required.  I have used quite a bit of data in process managers previously where the state is specific only to process manager.  But as I mentioned up front, this is a tricky situation.  The best is to steer clear of your live ARs until you are sure changes can be applied safely.

Comment: I've been giving this some thought and I don't know if using some 'status' on an AR makes it aware of a process manager.  Take an `Order`, as an example, it certainly has some status for its *life-cycle* but it is related to the business process.  So not necessarily related to a process manager but it is definitely aware of some form of business process.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the first part of your answer right from the start - sure storing some temp data isn't blocking, my bad. I agree with your point of only storing changes when it's safe, but including a state related to the saga in the ARs would defy the saga-agnostic aspect of the ARs themselves. Also an AR could take part in several sagas in different contexts. The general question still stands - is there any pattern of having a distributed transaction **without** involving a transaction per se while working in a concurrent environment?